# What are the best wiki options for SharePoint

Tags: 2007, wiki

We are using MOSS 2007 enterprise. Can anyone recommend a good wiki solution for us to use?

all the best

Comment: What are you trying to do?  What type of content, how many pages/topics, and how many users?  The question is pretty open ended.  I think Woody did a good job giving an overview of the SharePoint wiki:  http://www.endusersharepoint.com/2009/04/16/wiki-in-the-box-is-sharepoint-wiki-really-that-bad/

Answer (score 4):

I'm lifting the answer I wrote for a similar question on [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11462/sharepoint-wikis/80110#80110), since it seemed reasonably well-received there:

We run into this topic *all* the time, and the first question I have taken to asking people is "Why do you need a wiki"?  Almost always the answers are things "ease of editing", "multiple contributors", and "Word is to heavyweight".  *Very* rarely have we seen anyone ask for what I consider to be uniquely wiki-like features (special "magic" markup, fine grained version history showing changes, etc).  Also, they usually want some kind of categorization of things, not just completely free-form pages.

In the SharePoint world these things should scream "list" at you if you've been working with the tool for a while.  There is basically no particular reason to use a wiki for these knowledge base-style applications, especially since "ease of editing" usually directly conflicts with the idea of learning a special markup language for most user.  Through a couple of rich-text columns in there, and you're all set.  If you really don't like the built-in rich-text editor (yes the image uploading process is clunky and it doesn't work in Firefox), have someone in your organization go drop the 8 Benjamins and go get the [RadEditor for SharePoint](http://www.telerik.com/products/sharepoint/radeditor.aspx).  It should pretty much handle those concerns.

Generally once we've gotten over the "but it needs to be a wiki" dogma, we've had pretty good customer reception to just using lists.  In some cases, where a little more of a page templating facility was required we turned to using the WCM features of MOSS, which requires a little more up-front thought about templates, but also has a better out of the box experience for things like content snippets and image handling.

Answer (score 3):

MOSS 2007 provides a WIKI template for collab portals.  You can also use a WIKI page library to store your pages.  If you want to enhance the usability check this site.

Try this resource http://www.bitsofsharepoint.com/Site/Wiki.aspx

Answer (score 3):

Have a look at Confluence by Atlassian, it integrates with Sharepoint.

Sharepoint's wiki functionality is exceedingly dire in my opinion...

Comment: Amen to this. If only you didn't have to pay for Confluence on top of SharePoint.

Answer (score 1):

Definitely depends on what your trying to do. If your trying to implement some sort of Knowledge Management requirements then the following links might help you...

Sean Wallbridge did [a post a while back about using a SharePoint blog for knowledge management](http://blog.brainlitter.com/archive/2009/07/22/building-a-knowledge-blogging-system-in-sharepoint-a-simple-but-effective-method-of-replacing-key-office-email-correspondence-with-a-sharepoint-blog.aspx) We use this inhouse and I much prefer what it provides than the out-of-the-box SharePoint wiki lists. Especially being able to post content directly from MS word and using live writer.

There is also the [freely available Application templates](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/windowsserver/sharepoint/bb407286.aspx), one of which is a knowledge base that uses a wiki list as its main content repository.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this recent post regarding WiKi options for SharePoint 2010. [kwizcom-wiki-plus-for-sharepoint-2010](http://www.inspiredbytechnology.com/index.php/2011/02/25/kwizcom-wiki-plus-for-sharepoint-2010/)